# How to write a Junit test for phone number with 10 digits in JAVA

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, testcase

I'm trying to write a test case for phone number where only numbers are allowed to pass. How to write it in java using the object types.

I tried this where I hard coded the characters. But I want a solution better than this

```
TelephoneNumber ExtensionNUM = new TelephoneNumber();
ExtensionNUM.setExtensionNum("!@#$%^&*()_-+=}]{[|;:'<,>./?qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnmàrèhìp\òtù");
contactPreference.setTelephoneNumber(ExtensionNUM);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't look like a test, so I have a hard time understanding your question. Maybe check [ask]. Why don't you just set an invalid number and then check that the code under test rejects it? Is it really interesting to test all possible invalid characters getting rejected? I'd test different combinations of valid numbers (e.g., with / without country code, with / without extension) an empty string, and some almost valid ones, but not every possible unicode character getting rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're capturing this in an object, you can simply assert this fact in the constructor of the object:

```java
public USTelephoneNumber implement TelephoneNumber {
   public USTelephoneNumber(String number) {
    // here you can handle +1 formats
    // But of course Canada also uses +1, so +1 is just a sanity check
    // but you can also apply much more sophisticated logic (like length, or using external validation.
     if (!number.startsWith("+1")){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("%s is not a US number", number));
     }
     
     if (!number.replaceAll("[ ]","").replaceAll("+1","").matches("[0-9]+")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("%s is not all numbers",number));

   }
}
@Throws(IllegalArgumentException.class)
public testIsNotUsPhoneNumber() throws IllegalArgumentException {
    new USPhoneNumber("+48 158 610 715");
}


public testIsUsPhoneNumber() {
    new USPhoneNumber("+1 425 388 2588");
}
```